# Remove vertex.tooltips from ndtv d3movie

Tags: r, d3.js, networkd3

I'm plotting a dynamic network visulisation using the Statnet, networkd3, and ndtv packages.

In the [vignette](https://statnet.org/Workshops/ndtv-d3_vignette.html) for this package, the authors explain how to *"generate interactive html tooltips to be displayed when the vertices are clicked on"*:

```
render.d3movie(
  toy_epi_sim,
  render.par = render.par,
  plot.par = plot.par,
  vertex.cex = 0.9,
  vertex.col = "ndtvcol",
  edge.col = "darkgrey",
  vertex.border = "lightgrey",
  displaylabels = FALSE,
  vertex.tooltip = function(slice){paste('name:',slice%v%'vertex.names','<br>',
                                         'status:', slice%v%'testatus')},
  output.mode='htmlWidget')
```

However, I'd like to remove these tooltips, since by default they just show meaningless node IDs, and I'm already showing node labels instead.

Things like `vertex.tooltip = F` or `vertex.tooltip = NA` don't work - how do I turn off vertex tooltips?

This is the code I'm using:

```
render.d3movie(net, usearrows = T, label = "gmv_label",
               displaylabels = T,
               bg="#ffffff",
               edge.col = "#ff0063",
               vertex.col = "colo",
               vertex.cex = "amount",
               edge.lwd = 5,
               launchBrowser=T, filename= XXX,
               render.par=list(tween.frames = 30, show.time = F),
               plot.par=list(mar=c(0,0,0,0)))
```